# Leiningen 2 does not look in localrepo?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm using Leiningen 2 and am struggling to get it to recognize the local repository ($HOME/.m2)

I'm trying to use the [storm-rdbms(storm-contrib)](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/tree/master/storm-rdbms) which is not on clojar

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Using the lein-localrepo plugin, installed storm-rdbms under the .m2 local repository
2. The pom.xml shows this:

   ```
   <groupId>storm-rdbms</groupId>
   <artifactId>storm-rdbms</artifactId>
   <versioning>
       <versions>
         <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </versions>
   <lastUpdated>20130214173431</lastUpdated>
   </versioning>
   ```
3. my project.clj file :

   ```
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                   [storm "0.8.2"]
                   [storm-rdbms "0.1-SNAPSHOT"]]
    :plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.4.1"]]
    :repositories {"local" ~(str (.toURI (java.io.File. "~/.m2")))})
   ```
4. I run lein deps:

   ```
    Could not find artifact storm-rdbms:storm-rdbms:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
    This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
    Could not resolve dependencies
   ```

I've tried this with Maven as well, but Maven 3 is not even able to install the jar when following the directions from [here](http://stian.almaas.me/2012/08/adding-jars-to-local-repository-with.html).

Please shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you specifically want to have it setup as a local repo? If not, you could [use the git repo as a dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051516/clojure-and-leiningen-using-a-git-repository-as-dependency).

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try but I'm trying not to have too many plugins...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you run mvn install, storm-rdbms seems not to ?properly? install a pom when it installs the jar, which was preventing lein from finding it.

here are the full steps I used:

```
git clone git://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib.git
cd storm-contrib/storm-rdbms/
mvn install
cp pom.xml ~/.m2/repository/storm/storm-rdbms/0.1-SNAPSHOT/storm-rdbms.pom  

cd ~/my-storm-project 
emacs project.clj and add this dep:
 [storm/storm-rdbms "0.1-SNAPSHOT"]
lein deps
```

I'm not sure if this is because it's a sub project. I was unable to build the parent project because one of the other sub-projects was broken when I checked it out...

Comment: Hi Arthur thanks for your reply. I tried your steps and at mvn install It looks like storm-contrib-sqs did not build suscessfully. I removed that from the parent pom and it seems to have worked. Also thank you for pointing out that I have to copy the pom.xml over to the m2 repository. :) it works now.